# How sound-streams are represented in memory, and how on the harddisk?

Tags: audio

How can sounddata be represented as bytes, in memory and on the harddisk ?
And how is this data being forwarded to loudspeakers ? Is there some kind of framerate ?  If so, how to store this "frames", in arrays maybe ?
I wasn't able to find something about this on the net, if you know some links, I'd like to see them.
I'd also like to know if there are fileformat specs for mp3, mp4 files etc.

I hope this is the right place to ask, as this is a general programming question.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes represent waveforms. They can be raw waveforms (PCM) or compressed with a codec (MP3, AAC). The codec will convert the compressed bitstream to raw data and then this is sent to the speakers.

Have a look [here](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/LectureNotes/AudioData.html)

Comment: Awesome link ! Couldn't find this, maybe wrong search terms.. Thank you !